# Can I draw a simple paint pie chart like this?

Tags: android, layout, fragment, pie-chart

I'm not looking for anything fancy. I have tried to follow tutorials about pie and bar graphs, but a lot of the tutorials don't follow the guidelines of my app. In my app, in one of my fragment layouts, I would like to simply draw a pie chart of two values.

as simple as -

Draw Circle

(%value) of the circle is red. 
(other%value) of circle is blue.

Can this not be done this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to do the leg work when someone else has made it available.

I highly recommend HoloGraphLibrary.  I use it anytime I need to make a pie graph.
https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home

It is very easy to use and it looks great.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is the chart you describe, then I think adding any library is major overkill. This very simple example should give you some ideas. The `setPercentage()` method sets the size of the red area; the remainder will be blue. Please note that there is no exception handling implemented, and the percentage should be between 0 and 100, inclusive.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    SimplePieChart pie;

    @Override    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        pie = new SimplePieChart(this);
        pie.setPercentage(65);
        setContentView(pie);
    }

    public class SimplePieChart extends View
    {
        private RectF rect = new RectF();
        private Paint paint = new Paint();      
        private int percentage;

        public SimplePieChart(Context context)
        {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public SimplePieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        }

        public void setPercentage(int percentage)
        {
            this.percentage = percentage;
            invalidate();
        }

        public int getPercentage()
        {
            return percentage;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
        {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            if (w > h)
            {
                rect.set(w / 2 - h / 2, 0, w / 2 + h / 2, h);
            }
            else
            {
                rect.set(0, h / 2 - w / 2, w, h / 2 + w / 2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, 360 * percentage / 100, true, paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawArc(rect, 360 * percentage / 100, 360 - 360 * percentage / 100, true, paint);
        }               
    }
}
```